# 'enter' listener not firing on webkit (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, addeventlistener

I've got the following..

```
    qbox.addEventListener("enter", function(event){
        alert("tap!");
    }, false);
```

qbox is a textArea basically and whenever I enter the text and hit enter the `alert` box does not fire. If I replace `enter` with `keydown` it works for all of my `keydown` keys. So, I know the problem is with that particular thing. I want it ideally to fire when ever the user clicks submit or hits enter. I've tried `ENTER` and `submit` too but neither work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
qbox.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {

    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        alert("tap!");
    }

}, false);
```

Comment: How would I pick up clicks etc?

Answer (score 0):

`enter` is not an event. You should use the `keypress` event, then check if the key pressed was the enter key.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how I'd do this?

Comment: Change the event name to `"keypress"`, then check if the `keyCode` is `10` or `13`.